"Clear" button of input type=date, datepicker
I need to control the behavior and properties of the "Clear" button that appears in the bottom of the datepicker of the input type=date, for example, if I want to change the word "Clear" for "Delete" or if I want it to show a message every time I execute the clear button.
Does anybody lnows how to do something like this?
enter image description here
I cant find documentation about how to do it.

Those widgets are browser-dependent and controlled by the browser. You don't see the same UI in different browsers. You should use a date picker library or write your own if you want that functionality.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
